# Magento 1.9 Fast Loading Responsive Theme

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, rwd

Does anybody know of a fast loading responsive theme that works with Magento 1.9.
We don't need anything fancy - just main nav bar on the top, and 2-column category pages. Oh yes, we have a slider on the home page - that's about it.

We don't really need anything special, just need it to load fast and efficiently. Can you recommend something fast?

Answer (score 2):

Magento 1.9 comes with a FAST responsive theme. (Package RWD)

You will spend less time styling the built in theme then you would trying to make an off the shelf theme work properly in 1.9 In addition you can style only the things that need styling and include template that need to be included instead of files that are possibly from a previous version of Magento.